# Delete Id that has many values in link table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to perform a delete where the UserId belongs to a linked table that has many different areas that the user can belong to.
The Linked table has a userAreaID and a serviceAreaID and when i try and delete from the userID that matches the UserAreaID it says `Sequence contains more than one ...` I have made a queryin `LINQPad` that selects the the things I want to delete but cannot get it to go right iin the actual project.

```
from t in Tbl_User
where t.UserId == 21
select new {
     t.UserId,
     ServiceArea = new {t.UserAreaTbl_UserServiceAreaDetails},
     userInfo = new{t.UserName,t.Email}
}
```

I have tried a foreach over the query but it is not enumerable.
How should I try and achieve this?

This is the whole of my query which I set the Deleted flag to `True`.

```
var deleteRecord = (from t in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails
                    where ((t.tbl_User.UserId == id) && (t.serviceAreaID == id))
                    )**** no method showing up?

if (deleteRecord != null)
{
    deleteRecord.tbl_User.Deleted = true;

    // Submit
    // ======
    db.SubmitChanges();

    // Reload the Grid
    // ===============
    LoadGrid();
```

Comment: do you mean, UserId of table1 is present as foreign key in table2, table3, table4?? or what??

Comment: userId is is primary key in user table and linked to userAreaID in Tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails. which has a searviceAreaID that can be many service areas that belong to the ServiceArea table.`var deleteRecord = (from t in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails
                                            where (t.tbl_User.UserId == id) && (t.serviceAreaID == id)
                                            ).`

Comment: The Above is what I am trying but `.Single()` or any method will not appear.

Comment: Your `no method shows up` is because you dont have a `select t` after your `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var dr in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails.Where(t => (t.tbl_User.UserId == id) && (t.serviceAreaID == id)))
{
    dr.tbl_User.Deleted = true;
}
```